Why $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ is the double cover of $SO(n)$?
Given a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and a quadratic form $\Phi$ on $V$, the Clifford group of $\Phi$ is the group, $$\Gamma(\Phi)=\{x\in\operatorname{Cl}(\Phi)^*:\alpha(x)vx^{-1}\in V\:\:\forall v\in V\}$$
The map $N:\operatorname{Cl}(\Phi)\rightarrow \operatorname{Cl}(\Phi)$ given by
$$N(x)=x\bar x$$
is called the norm of $\operatorname{Cl}(\Phi)$. We define the pinor group $\operatorname{Pin}(n)$ as the kernel of the homomorphism $N:\Gamma\rightarrow\mathbb R^*\cdot 1$, and the spinor group $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ as $\operatorname{Pin}(n)\cap\Gamma^+$. That's the all information I learnt yet from Clifford Algebras, Clifford Groups, and a Generalization of the Quaternions. I also understand the action of this Clifford group on $V$ by the twisted adjoint operation $x\cdot v=\alpha(x)vx^{-1}$. Which is the reflection about the hyperplane orthogonal to the vector $x$. From the norm preserving condition I get the complete sense of how the spinor group is related to $O(n)$.
$$\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)=\{x\in\operatorname{Cl}_n:\alpha(x)vx^{-1}\in\mathbb R^n\:\:\forall v\in\mathbb R^n,\:\:\:N(x)=x\bar{x}=1\}$$
I also understand the surjective homomorphism $\mathcal A:\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R^n)\rightarrow SO(n)$. But the main issue arises when I try to show that this is a double cover of $SO(n)$. The theorem which I want to prove is,

Theorem 1.40. (Sepanski) $\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)$ is the connected ($n\geq 2$) simply connected $(n\geq 3)$ two-fold cover of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$. The covering homomorphism is given by $\mathcal A$ with $\ker\mathcal A=\{\pm1\}$ with an exact sequence: $$\{1\}\rightarrow\{\pm1\}\rightarrow \operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)\stackrel{\mathcal A}{\rightarrow}\operatorname{SO}(n)\rightarrow\{I\}$$

I never formally taught Algebraic Topology, but from my previous post I learnt so many new things. And from the comment I find the following proposition,

Proposition 1.32. (Hatcher) The map $p_*:\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0)\rightarrow(X,x_0)$ induced by a covering space. The number of sheets of the covering space equals the index of $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$ in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$.

I guess, We can use this proposition to say $\mathcal A$ is a double cover for $SO(n)$ if we know that $\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R^n)$ is the universal cover of $SO(n)$. Because then $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$ will be trivial and we already knew that $\pi_1(SO(n))=\mathbb Z_2,n\geq3$. But I don't know how to show the $\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)$ is the universal cover of $SO(n)$. I search on google but it seems like most of the place it is the definition of $\operatorname{Spin}$ (double cover of $SO(n)$). From here I don't understand how to show this from my existing knowledge. Any suggestion/hint/resource will be appreciated. TIA

For sake of clarity I explicitly mention my questions here:

So, we define the $\operatorname{Pin}(n)$ or $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$  as the kernel of $N$ and $N^+$ (which are subgroup of $\Gamma(\Phi)$) respectively. So, I understand the group part completely and still the manifold part is unintuitive to me.

I guess while writing $O(n) \cong \{\pm 1\} \backslash \operatorname{Pin}(n)$ and $SO(n)\cong \{\pm 1\} \backslash \operatorname{Spin}(n)$, I have the double covering idea in my mind. But if I forgot that then how can I show this? Right now I am using this information to confirm these are covering space (kinda circular argument).



great question, it will get people rethinking all the minute details of Cl, Pin, Spin

My previous bounty was wasted. Should I add a bounty for this question?

@ Dr. Antidode:  just added one

So you want to know why the spin group is simply-connected?

Dale Husemoller, Fibre bundles, 12. Clifford Algebras, Theorem 9.2.

I guess I can show that $\operatorname{Spin}$ is simply connected. However, the whole idea of Clifford, from algebra to group actions and the universal covering space of $SO(n)$, seems scattered to me @MoisheKohan Maybe my lack of knowledge of Algebraic Topology is the main reason.

Are you aware f the fact that if $p: X\to Y$ is a covering map of manifolds and $X$ is simply connected, then $p$ is the universal covering? You really need to do some reading of basic algebraic topology, otherwise, you will keep getting stuck on such small issues when you work with Lie groups.

I understand that after reading the hatcher section 1.3. I guess I have two questions (added) remaining before leaving this section. Can you say something about that? Thanks for your patience and helpful comments. @MoisheKohan

The "manifold part" should be answered by this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520113/lie-group-structure-of-the-spin-group

So I take your questions to be the following, rephrased from the end of your post:

You want to know why $\ker N:\Gamma(\Phi)\to\mathbb{R}^\times$ defines a Lie group
You want to know how to show that $\mathcal{A}:\text{Spin}(n)\to\text{SO}(n)$ is a double covering (when $n>2$).

Let's start with 1. It is easy to show that Clifford multiplication on $\text{Cl}(V,\Phi)$ is smooth, since multiplication is bilinear. Furthermore, $\text{Cl}(V,\Phi)^\times$ is an open subset of $\text{Cl}(V,\Phi)$. See this post: Lie group structure of the spin group. Now, we can define $N:\text{Cl}(V,\Phi)^\times\to\text{Cl}(V,\Phi)^\times$ as $N(x)=xx^T$, where the transpose is defined using a basis for $V$, by the formula $(e_{i_1}\dots e_{i_k})^T=e_{i_k}\dots e_{i_1}$. Since multiplication is smooth, this map is smooth, and it is easy show that $N(xy)=(xy)(xy)^T=xyy^Tx^T=(-1)^{|y|}(-1)^{|y^T|}N(x)N(y)=N(x)N(y)$ on pure degree elements. Therefore, $N$ is in fact a Lie group homomorphism. By standard Lie group theory, $\ker N$ is a closed subgroup of $\text{Cl}(V,\Phi)^\times$. Therefore, $\ker N$, together with the restricted Clifford multiplication map, is a Lie group, namely $\text{Pin}(n)$. Then $\text{Spin}(n)$ is just the identity component of $\text{Pin}(n)$, and is therefore a closed subgroup of $\text{Pin}(n)$. In conclusion, $\text{Spin}(n)\subset\text{Cl}(V,\phi)$ together with Clifford multiplication is a Lie group.
Now we turn to 2., so we want to show that $\mathcal{A}:\text{Spin}(n)\to\text{SO}(n)$ is a double cover. To do this, we have to identify $\ker\mathcal{A}$. I'll follow https://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/courses/261/23.pdf page 77. Suppose $\varphi\in\text{Spin}(n)$ is such that $\varphi v\varphi^*=v$ for all $v\in V$. Then it must hold that $\varphi v=v\varphi$, since $\alpha$ acts trivially on $\text{Spin}(n)$. Choose an orthogonal basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ for $V$ (w.r.t. $\Phi$), and say that $\varphi=x+e_ky$ with $x$ even and $y$ odd, and neither containing a factor of $e_k$. Then $e_k$ commutes with $x$ and $y$. But then $\varphi v=v\varphi$ implies that $y=0$, if we take $v=e_k$. Therefore $\varphi$ contains no monomials with a factor of $e_k$, for any $1\leq k\leq n$, so in fact $\varphi\in\mathbb{R}^\times$. But then, since $\varphi\in\ker N$, we have shown that $\ker\mathcal{A}=\{1, -1\}$. It follows that the index of $\ker\mathcal{A}$ in $\text{Spin}(n)$ is $2$, so that $\mathcal{A}$ is a double covering. You can see that it is surjective by looking at $\mathcal{A}:\text{Pin}(n)\to\text{O}(n)$. Say $w,v\in V$, with $w\in\text{Pin}(n)$ (so $w^2=1$), then
$$\mathcal{A}(w)v=wvw^*=-wvw=(v-v)-wvw=v-vw^2-wvw=v-2\langle v,w\rangle w$$
where the last step uses the defining relationship of the Clifford algebra. Now, use the fact that $\text{O}(n)$ is generated by refelections (e.g. the Cartan-Dieudonné theorem) to conclude that $\mathcal{A}$ is surjective, also between $\text{Spin}(n)$ and $\text{SO}(n)$.
Finally, to show that $\text{Spin}(n)$ (for $n\geq 3$) is simply connected, one proceeds by first identifying the fundamental groups of $\text{SO}(n)$. We start with $\text{SO}(3)$, see e.g. here: Homeomorphism of $SO(3)$?. This shows that $\text{SO}(3)\cong\mathbb{R}P^3$. It follows that $\pi_1(\text{SO}(3))=\mathbb{Z}/2$. Next, observe that $\text{SO}(n+1)$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{S}^n\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, with stabiliser isomorphic to $\text{SO}(n)\subset\text{SO}(n+1)$. It follows that there is a fibration $\text{SO}(n)\to\text{SO}(n+1)\to\mathbb{S}^n$, by the orbit-stabiliser theorem for Lie groups. Every fibration induces a long exact sequence of homotopy groups. In this particular case, $\pi_2(\mathbb{S}^n)=\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^n)=\{0\}$ for $n\geq 3$, and hence the long exact sequence implies $\pi_1(\text{SO}(n))\cong\pi_1(\text{SO}(n+1))$. By induction, this shows that $\pi_1(\text{SO}(n))=\mathbb{Z}/2$ for $n\geq 3$. Consequently, the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ is a double covering map implies that $\text{Spin}(n)$ is simply connected, since its fundamental group must have index $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Right, the transpose is defined using an orthoogonal basis perhaps.  Also, can we in fact prove that the spin group is simply connected directly?  Proving that the fundamental group of $SO(n)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$ for $n\ge 3$ is altogether algebraic topology. So, can we show the simply connectedness directly?

What exactly do you mean by "directly" proving it? You mean without appealing to the fundamental group of $\text{SO}(n)$?

Yes indeed,  can you prove that the object constructed is simply connected, without the knowledge of $\pi_1$ of the $SO(n)$ ( that uses I think the long exact sequence of a fibration), and you need $\pi_1(SO(3))$ to get started.

It might be possible, but I don't know why you would want to do that. What you want to avoid is some kind of circular logic where you say that the spin group is a double covering because it is simply connected, and that it is simply connected because it is the universal covering of the special orthogonal group, since it is a double covering. But in the above, we show that it is a double covering without appealing to any topological arguments.

Well, alternatively you can also add/sketch  a proof that $\pi_1(SO(n))$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$, since that is not an obvious fact. Also, is it clear that the morphism to $SO(n)$ is surjective?

Fair points, I've addressed those.

Getting better!   Now, I think we prove that $\pi_1(SO(3))= \mathbb{Z}/2$ by exhibiting a two-fold cover from the units of the quaternions ( $S^3$) to the group in question.   So in this case we know exactly that the spin group is simply connected.  Yeah, I had a hope that it could be shown for every $n\ge 3$.  There is something that can be done for $n=4$ though...

Sure, we can do something using the exceptional isomorphisms for spin groups. But I am not aware of any geometric object for $\text{Spin}(n)$ to act on transitively, in a way that does not factor through the special orthogonal group. So I don't think that what you're suggesting would work as a general argument.

I have a feeling that there is a fibration involving the spin groups, just like the so's, that would show simple connectedness directly

You can let $\text{Spin}(n)$ act on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ through $\text{SO}(n)$. Since $\text{Spin}(n-1)\subset\text{Spin}(n)$ maps to $\text{SO}(n-1)\subset\text{SO}(n)$, you could then use the argument directly for $\text{Spin}(n)$, using that $\text{Spin}(3)$ is simply connected because $\text{Spin}(3)\cong\mathbb{S}^3$. I'm not aware of another natural geometric object for $\text{Spin}(n)$ to act on (without factoring through $\text{SO}(n)$), but if you have any ideas, feel free to share.

Actually, I had the idea to let $\text{Spin}(n)$ act on the sphere in spinor space $\Delta_n$. However, the isotropy group in this case will generally not be $\text{Spin}(n-1)$, so that does not work.

There seems to be a lot of interesting stuff there, including the (Bott) periodicity,
